# AngularJS: how render directive from controller's variable?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

In my controller:

```
$scope.directiveName = 'hello-world';
```

My directive:

```
App.directive('helloWorld',
[
function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'EAC',
    link: function(scope, ele, atr) {
      console.log('hello world from directive');
    }
  }
}]);
```

in my html:

```
<div class="{{directiveName}}"></div>
```

Why this is not work? How can I do this behavior?

Comment: Try using ng-class:

    <div ng-class="directiveName"></div>

Comment: It's don't work. And <div ng-class="{ "{{directiveName}}": true}"></div>  don't work too.

Comment: That's because angular does not pick that up. i.e your template (dom element) won't get recompiled. Do you mind adding more information on what you're trying to achieve? It seems like you want to render different templates based on a variable... If so, I suggest you create a directive that defines which template to render based on a given attribute (and setup a $watch on it, so it you take care of recompiling the new template)

Answer (score 0):

just use `ng-bind` directive to add your custom directive to html

```
<div class="ng-bind:'directiveName'"></div>
```

[Angular DOC](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBind)

**update**
your directive supports **class**,**attribute** and **tag**. so you can use your directive as in another format also.

```
<div {{directiveName}}></div>
```

Comment: This work if i write <div class="ng-bind='hello-world'"></div>, but don't work <div class="ng-bind=directiveName"></div> and <div class="ng-bind:directiveName"></div>

Comment: wrap directiveName inside single quotes

Comment: directiveName - it is variable with string value

Comment: Assigning it from controller is not that much good idea. use another format